# Indirect Apache HttpClient and javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I am using a library (Dasein) that uses Apache HttpClient.

When I am trying to make an HTTPS connection (via Dasein and thus HttpClient) to my server with a self-signed cert, I am getting 

`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match`

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <172.16.2.152> != 
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:130)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)

I already have imported the certificate to a truststore and am using -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore.
To fix this non-matching hostname, I have in my code

```
    javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier fakeHostnameVerifier = new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(fakeHostnameVerifier);

    com.sun.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier fakeSunHostnameVerifier = new com.sun.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String string, String string1) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(fakeSunHostnameVerifier);
```

When I try to connect directly from my code to that server via `new URL("https://my.server.com/api/versions")`, everything is fine thanks to the hostNameVerifier. It seems that it does not propagate or is overridden when HttpClient is called.

Any ideas how to solve this? E.g. some VM parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've simply added the host name entry from the cert to my /etc/hosts and am refering to that FQDN. Problem solved.